# Where can I edit/see the HTML of this Wordpress free theme?

Tags: child-theme, html

the answer to this one will probably be obvious to many of you, but I recently decided to make a website for my girlfriend and expand my knowledge while doing that. So here is my dilemma:

I am using the Blossom Mommy Blog theme, which is a child of the Blossom Feminine theme.

Below a single post page, there is a previous post/ next post navigation menu, that has some text in English and I want to change that to be in Bulgarian (see attached file below). I was able to see this in the browser debugger, but I can't seem to find where this comes from in the theme files themself, so any help would be really appreciated!

[image: Here's what I want to change]

With many thanks,
Dobri

Comment: It is probably coded in a way that allows you to use `.mo` and `.po` localisation files. That is much more robust than hard-coding the Bulgarian into the theme file.  Download the `Poedit` program. You may need to start a new Bulgarian translation file, but perhaps there is one already, either in `/theme-folder/languages` or in `/wp-content/languages/themes`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand/learn how WP generates pages. It is all done through template files, which are files that contain the PHP and HTML code to generate the HTML. There are no HTML pages (basically) that are used by WP themes. There are templates that query the database and produce HTML output according to the code in the template.

Start by looking here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/ , which is also the tutorial for how themes are built and work.

Understanding how templates work to display pages is an important part of learning how WP works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text through language files ( you can find in wp-content/languages/themes ) or using the plugin that is used for translation of the strings like the loco translator.

Or you can override the single.php file in the child theme and then find the function that is creating the next and previous link. After finding the line of code that is used for creating the next and previous link you can change the text from previous/next to anything else that you want.